# how to recall variables from array in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have the following system variables:

```
$var01="this is var01"
$var02="this is var02"
$var03="this is var03"
$Var04="this is var04"
```

I want to use a for loop to recall each of them:

```
for i in {0..4}
do
 echo "content of var$i is: $[var$i]"
done
```

but the above for loop gives me an error saying "bad substitution".
How should I construct echo parameter so to get the following result:

```
content of var01 is: this is var01
content of var02 is: this is var02
content of var03 is: this is var03
content of var04 is: this is var04
```

Comment: Another approach: `for i in var{0..4}; do echo "${!i}"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with bash >= 4.3:

```
for i in {0..4}; do x="var$i"; echo "${!x}"; done
```

See: [Nameref](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#examples)